Implementing am5 charts: Error: export 'RadarChart' (imported as 'am5radar') was not found in '@amcharts/amcharts5/radar' (module has no exports)
I am implementing a project using am5charts but after importing the charts I end up with the error on running the project, no erros on the component file but on trying to run the application I end up getting

./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:26:53-76 - Error:
export 'RadarChart' (imported as 'am5radar') was not found in
'@amcharts/amcharts5/radar' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:64:22-55 - Error:
export 'AxisRendererCircular' (imported as 'am5radar') was not found
in '@amcharts/amcharts5/radar' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:71:35-54 - Error:
export 'ValueAxis' (imported as 'am5xy') was not found in
'@amcharts/amcharts5/xy' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:79:22-53 - Error:
export 'AxisRendererRadial' (imported as 'am5radar') was not found in
'@amcharts/amcharts5/radar' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:92:35-57 - Error:
export 'CategoryAxis' (imported as 'am5xy') was not found in
'@amcharts/amcharts5/xy' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:97:38-68 - Error:
export 'RadarColumnSeries' (imported as 'am5radar') was not found in
'@amcharts/amcharts5/radar' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:112:38-68 - Error:
export 'RadarColumnSeries' (imported as 'am5radar') was not found in
'@amcharts/amcharts5/radar' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:136:53-76 - Error:
export 'RadarChart' (imported as 'am5radar') was not found in
'@amcharts/amcharts5/radar' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:174:22-55 - Error:
export 'AxisRendererCircular' (imported as 'am5radar') was not found
in '@amcharts/amcharts5/radar' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:181:35-54 - Error:
export 'ValueAxis' (imported as 'am5xy') was not found in
'@amcharts/amcharts5/xy' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:189:22-53 - Error:
export 'AxisRendererRadial' (imported as 'am5radar') was not found in
'@amcharts/amcharts5/radar' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:202:35-57 - Error:
export 'CategoryAxis' (imported as 'am5xy') was not found in
'@amcharts/amcharts5/xy' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:207:38-68 - Error:
export 'RadarColumnSeries' (imported as 'am5radar') was not found in
'@amcharts/amcharts5/radar' (module has no exports)
./src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:222:38-68 - Error:
export 'RadarColumnSeries' (imported as 'am5radar') was not found in
'@amcharts/amcharts5/radar' (module has no exports)

this is what I have done so far
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import * as am5 from '@amcharts/amcharts5';
import * as am5xy from '@amcharts/amcharts5/xy';
import * as am5radar from "@amcharts/amcharts5/radar";
import am5themes_Animated from "@amcharts/amcharts5/themes/Animated";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  private root1!: am5.Root;
  private root2!: am5.Root;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.initRadarChart1();
    this.initRadarChart2();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.root1) {
      this.root1.dispose();
    }
    if (this.root2) {
      this.root2.dispose();
    }
  }

  private initRadarChart1() {
    const element = document.getElementById('kt_charts_widget_19_chart_1');
    if (!element) return;

    this.root1 = am5.Root.new(element);

    this.root1.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(this.root1)]);

    const chart = this.root1.container.children.push(
      am5radar.RadarChart.new(this.root1, {
        panX: false,
        panY: false,
        wheelX: 'panX',
        wheelY: 'zoomX',
        innerRadius: am5.percent(20),
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 180,
      })
    );

    const data = [
      { category: 'Research', value: 80, full: 100, columnSettings: { fill: am5.color('#0dcaf0') } },
      { category: 'Marketing', value: 35, full: 100, columnSettings: { fill: am5.color('#dc3545') } },
      { category: 'Distribution', value: 92, full: 100, columnSettings: { fill: am5.color('#0d6efd') } },
      { category: 'Human Resources', value: 68, full: 100, columnSettings: { fill: am5.color('#198754') } },
    ];

    const xRenderer = am5radar.AxisRendererCircular.new(this.root1, {});
    xRenderer.labels.template.setAll({ radius: 10 });
    xRenderer.grid.template.setAll({ forceHidden: true });

    const xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
      am5xy.ValueAxis.new(this.root1, {
        renderer: xRenderer,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        strictMinMax: true,
        numberFormat: "#'%'",
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(this.root1, {}),
      })
    );

    const yRenderer = am5radar.AxisRendererRadial.new(this.root1, { minGridDistance: 20 });
    yRenderer.labels.template.setAll({
      centerX: am5.p100,
      fontWeight: '500',
      fontSize: 18,
      fill: am5.color('#6c757d'),
      templateField: 'columnSettings',
    });
    yRenderer.grid.template.setAll({ forceHidden: true });

    const yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
      am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(this.root1, {
        categoryField: 'category',
        renderer: yRenderer,
      })
    );

    yAxis.data.setAll(data);

    const series1 = chart.series.push(
      am5radar.RadarColumnSeries.new(this.root1, {
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        clustered: false,
        valueXField: 'full',
        categoryYField: 'category',
        fill: this.root1.interfaceColors.get('alternativeBackground'),
      })
    );

    series1.columns.template.setAll({
      width: am5.p100,
      fillOpacity: 0.08,
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      cornerRadius: 20,
    });

    series1.data.setAll(data);

    const series2 = chart.series.push(
      am5radar.RadarColumnSeries.new(this.root1, {
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        clustered: false,
        valueXField: 'value',
        categoryYField: 'category',
      })
    );

    series2.columns.template.setAll({
      width: am5.p100,
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      tooltipText: '{category}: {valueX}%',
      cornerRadius: 20,
      templateField: 'columnSettings',
    });

    series2.data.setAll(data);

    series1.appear(1000);
    series2.appear(1000);
    chart.appear(1000, 100);
  }

  private initRadarChart2() {
    const element = document.getElementById('kt_charts_widget_19_chart_2');
    if (!element) return;

    this.root2 = am5.Root.new(element);

    this.root2.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(this.root2)]);

    const chart = this.root2.container.children.push(
      am5radar.RadarChart.new(this.root2, {
        panX: false,
        panY: false,
        wheelX: 'panX',
        wheelY: 'zoomX',
        innerRadius: am5.percent(20),
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 180,
      })
    );

    const data = [
      { category: 'Research', value: 40, full: 100, columnSettings: { fill: am5.color('#0dcaf0') } },
      { category: 'Marketing', value: 50, full: 100, columnSettings: { fill: am5.color('#dc3545') } },
      { category: 'Distribution', value: 80, full: 100, columnSettings: { fill: am5.color('#0d6efd') } },
      { category: 'Human Resources', value: 70, full: 100, columnSettings: { fill: am5.color('#198754') } },
    ];

    const xRenderer = am5radar.AxisRendererCircular.new(this.root2, {});
    xRenderer.labels.template.setAll({ radius: 10 });
    xRenderer.grid.template.setAll({ forceHidden: true });

    const xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
      am5xy.ValueAxis.new(this.root2, {
        renderer: xRenderer,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        strictMinMax: true,
        numberFormat: "#'%'",
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(this.root2, {}),
      })
    );

    const yRenderer = am5radar.AxisRendererRadial.new(this.root2, { minGridDistance: 20 });
    yRenderer.labels.template.setAll({
      centerX: am5.p100,
      fontWeight: '500',
      fontSize: 18,
      fill: am5.color('#6c757d'),
      templateField: 'columnSettings',
    });
    yRenderer.grid.template.setAll({ forceHidden: true });

    const yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
      am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(this.root2, {
        categoryField: 'category',
        renderer: yRenderer,
      })
    );

    yAxis.data.setAll(data);

    const series1 = chart.series.push(
      am5radar.RadarColumnSeries.new(this.root2, {
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        clustered: false,
        valueXField: 'full',
        categoryYField: 'category',
        fill: this.root2.interfaceColors.get('alternativeBackground'),
      })
    );

    series1.columns.template.setAll({
      width: am5.p100,
      fillOpacity: 0.08,
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      cornerRadius: 20,
    });

    series1.data.setAll(data);

    const series2 = chart.series.push(
      am5radar.RadarColumnSeries.new(this.root2, {
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        clustered: false,
        valueXField: 'value',
        categoryYField: 'category',
      })
    );

    series2.columns.template.setAll({
      width: am5.p100,
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      tooltipText: '{category}: {valueX}%',
      cornerRadius: 20,
      templateField: 'columnSettings',
    });

    series2.data.setAll(data);

    series1.appear(1000);
    series2.appear(1000);
    chart.appear(1000, 100);
  }
}

I have imported the necessary modules
{
  "name": "win",
  "version": "8.2.3",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build",
    "serve": "ng serve",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "rtl": "webpack --config=rtl.config.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts5": "^5.1.7",
    "@amcharts/amcharts5-fonts": "^5.0.1",
    "@amcharts/amcharts5-geodata": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "@coreui/angular": "^4.7.19",
    "@coreui/icons-angular": "^5.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.3.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "8.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "2.11.8",
    "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^12.2.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-navigations": "^25.1.40",
    "@types/chartjs": "^0.0.31",
    "angular-datatables": "^17.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.16.0",
    "animate.css": "4.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.37.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.3",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.3",
    "clipboard": "2.0.11",
    "countup.js": "^2.8.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.11.3",
    "datatables.net-bs5": "^1.11.3",
    "igniteui-angular": "^17.0.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "line-awesome": "1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.7.4",
    "ng-inline-svg-2": "^15.0.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^6.0.1",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-clipboard": "16.0.0",
    "ngx-countup": "^13.1.0",
    "nouislider": "^15.7.0",
    "npm": "^10.8.1",
    "object-path": "0.11.8",
    "or": "^0.2.0",
    "primeng": "^17.13.0",
    "prism-themes": "1.9.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "sweetalert2": "11.4.8",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "undici": "^6.11.1",
    "vite": "^5.2.8",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^7.2.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.28",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.21",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.4",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.9",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.5",
    "@types/object-path": "0.11.1",
    "@types/prismjs": "1.26.0",
    "@types/sass-loader": "8.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "del": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.39.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.1",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.2",
    "rtlcss-webpack-plugin": "4.0.7",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "5.1.4"
  }
}

I have tried running the application on stackblitz am getting the same error, what could I be doing wrong

issue not reproducible stackblitz
